# Editing elements in a list in python

Tags: python, regex, string

How do I remove a character from an element in a list?

Example:

```
mylist = ['12:01', '12:02']
```

I want to remove the colon from the time stamps in a file, so I can more easily convert them to a 24hour time.  Right now I am trying to loop over the elements in the list and search for the one's containing a colon and doing a substitute.

```
for num in mylist:
    re.sub(':', '', num)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Help!

Comment: It does not work because strings are immutable. `re.sub` actually **returns** a string but you are not assigning it. Read the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The list comprehension solution is the most Pythonic one, but, there's an important twist:

```
mylist[:] = [s.replace(':', '') for s in mylist]
```

If you assign to `mylist`, the barename, as in the other answer, rather than to `mylist[:]`, the "whole-list slice", as I recommend, you're really doing something very different than "replacing entries *in the list*": you're making a new list and just rebinding the barename that you were previously using to refer to the old list.

If that old list is being referred to by multiple names (including entries in containers), this rebinding doesn't affect any of those: for example, if you have a function which takes `mylist` as an argument, the barename assignment has any effect only locally to the function, and doesn't alter what the caller sees as the list's contents.

Assigning to the whole-list slice, `mylist[:] = ...`, *alters the list object* rather than mucking around with switching barenames' bindings -- now that list is truly altered and, no matter how it's referred to, the new value is what's seen.  For example, if you have a function which takes `mylist` as an argument, the whole-list slice assignment alters what the caller sees as the list's contents.

The key thing is knowing exactly what effect you're after -- most commonly you'll want to alter the list object, so, if one has to guess, whole-list slice assignment is usually the best guess to take;-).  Performance-wise, it makes no difference either way (except that the barename assignment, if it keeps both old and new list objects around, will take up more memory for whatever lapse of time both objects are still around, of course).

Answer (score 17):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate a new list:

```
>>> mylist = ['12:01', '12:02']
>>> mylist = [s.replace(':', '') for s in mylist]
>>> print mylist
['1201', '1202']
```

The reason that your solution doesn't work is that `re.sub` returns a **new** string -- strings are immutable in Python, so `re.sub` can't modify your existing strings.

Comment: List comprehension to the rescue!

Comment: Is there any advantage of list comprehensions to standard for loops, or just readability or length of the code?

Comment: @TooAngel: It is more awesome ;)

Comment: @TooAngel: In addition to readability and reduced code length, list comprehensions also execute faster.

Comment: @Daniel Stutzbach: Not always. It depends on what you are doing in the list comprehension (e.g. if you are using nested list comprehension). Sometimes you can gain a lot more performance using ordinary `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks ya'll!  I am totally new to python (obviously =)  and I had no idea about list comprehensions.  I have been looking for something like this.  You just saved me so much time!

Comment: @Felix Kling: Obviously a better algorithm will be faster.  I was referring only to cases where the list comprehension and the for loop are identical except for the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i, num in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = num.replace(':','')
```

Comment: By default, I would go for this solution because you re-nest the new strings into the same list object. List comprehension approach detaches the result from original list pointer. When the list is property of a complex object, and you want that complex object to have the updated list, you will have to assign the new list back to a property, which is very un-pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the return of re.sub back in the list. Below is for a new list. But you can do that for mylist as well.

```
mylist = ['12:01', '12:02']
tolist = []
for num in mylist:
  a = re.sub(':', '', num)
  tolist.append(a)

print tolist
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in python are immutable, meaning no function can change the contents of an existing string, only provide a new string. Here's [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538663/newbie-question-why-are-python-strings-and-tuples-are-made-immutable).

See [here](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) for a discussion on string types that can be changed. In practice though, it's better to adjust to the immutability of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list comprehension, you can also use a `map` call:

```
mylist = ['12:01', '12:02']
map(lambda f: f.replace(':', ''), mylist)
```

Returns:

```
['1201', '1202']
```