# Python: How to remove html entities from list items?

Tags: python, html-entities

I have a list with results from re.findall from a web page.

List items contains & # 171; & # 8211; etc.

How do i remove these substrings from list items ?

Comment: please post more about the list and possibly about the regex you are using. Possibly you can filter them from regexp itself. or, you can process the list you obtained.

Comment: Use an HTML parser rather than trying to parse HTML with a regex.

Comment: unescape from HTMLParser() does not work.
It does not escape characters like & # 171; & # 8211; etc.

My list contains titles from a blog with some html entities numbers.

I need a way to process the final list and remove these substrings.

Comment: Well, those are broken; they should not have spaces. So if they aren't being parsed, they are being parsed correctly.

Comment: @kindall, these are not broken.

I put the spaces because stackoverflow editor printed these as characters.

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094659/editing-elements-in-a-list-in-python

i managed to solve my problem.

I wanted the final list with the results to be processed.

#!/usr/bin/python

import re

mylist = ['bla bla', 'bla &#162; bla bla &#8364;']

print mylist

tolist = []
for num in mylist:
  a = re.sub(':', '', num)
  a = re.sub('&[^\s]*;', '', num)
  tolist.append(a)

print tolist

Comment: Oh. In that case you should use BeautifulSoup 4; it will parse those for you.