# re in list of lists

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of lists (irregular lengths of sub-lists), on which I want to perform `re` operations but can't get it to work. I'm sure I'm missing something profane; could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Consider the following code snippets:

```
test_list = [ # sample list of lists in which I want to replace the "\n"
      ["test\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", "another test\n", "spam"],
      ["egg\n\n", "house"],
      ["\n\nabc", "def\n", "\n\n\nghi", "jklm\n\n", "nop(e)", "\nqrst\n"],
      ["uvw\n", "\n\nx", "yz\n\n"]]
for item in test_list:
    for subitem in item:
    re.sub('\n', '___', subitem)
pprint.pprint(test_list)
```

Output:

```
[['test\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 'another test\n', 'spam'],
 ['egg\n\n', 'house'],
 ['\n\nabc', 'def\n', '\n\n\nghi', 'jklm\n\n', 'nop(e)', '\nqrst\n'],
 ['uvw\n', '\n\nx', 'yz\n\n']]
```

(The output is unchanged - the replacement didn't work.)

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Edit:**

Thanks [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) for the link. The first advice from the referenced question - **string being immutable!** - was helpful but I cannot get it to work for the **list of lists**.

Following the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094659/editing-elements-in-a-list-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507319/python-list-comprehension-list-of-lists), I my code looks like this:

```
newtestlist = [[re.sub("\n", '_', item) for subitem in item] for item in testlist]
```

However, it doesn't work (throwing a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` - I'm not referring correctly to the subitems of my list.)
Can someone point me in the right direction? Many thanks

Comment: I think you want to call `sub` with `subitem` not `item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple list of list, your edited solution should have worked, but you have to change `re.sub("\n", '_', item)` to `re.sub("\n", '_', subitem)` as @Mark Meyer noted. I noticed a typo as well; `testlist` instead of `test_list`. Here's what I tested and worked with your `test_list`

```
[[re.sub(r'\n', r'_', item) for item in sub_list] for sub_list in test_list]
```

But if you have a deeply nested list, I think you'll need a recursive function.

```
def sub_nested(l, regin, regout):
    """Recursive function to do string replace in a nested list"""
    retlist = []
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            retlist.append(sub_nested(item, regin, regout))
        else:
            retlist.append(re.sub(regin, regout, item))
    return retlist
```

Testing it on your input list.

```
sub_nested(test_list, r'\n', r'___')

Out: 
 [['test________________________', 'another test___', 'spam'],
 ['egg______', 'house'],
 ['______abc', 'def___', '_________ghi', 'jklm______', 'nop(e)', '___qrst___'],
 ['uvw___', '______x', 'yz______']]
```