# Does Python do slice-by-reference on strings?

Tags: python, string

I want to know if when I do something like

```
a = "This could be a very large string..."
b = a[:10]
```

a new string is created or a view/iterator is returned

Comment: Note that you can use `itertools.islice` for the latter.

Comment: When you ran it, and used `id()` to check the object identity, what did you learn?

Comment: @S.Lott: A view would have a different `id()` to the object it was a view of. So that doesn't actually teach you anything. Doing `type()` is more useful.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[Python does slice-by-copy](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-May/079689.html), meaning every time you slice (except for [very trivial slices](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-May/079694.html), such as `a[:]`), it copies all of the data into a new string object.

According to [one of the developers](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-May/079699.html), this choice was made because

> The [slice-by-reference] approach is more complicated, harder to implement
>   and may lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> a = "a long string with 500,000 chars ..."
> b = a[0]
> del a
> ```
>
> With the slice-as-copy design the string `a` is immediately freed. The
>   slice-as-reference design would keep the 500kB string in memory although
>   you are only interested in the first character.

Apparently, if you absolutely *need* a view into a string, you can use a [`memoryview`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) object.

Comment: @BlueRaja-Danny-Pflughoeft What are the other possible kinds of trivial slices?

Comment: @sandeeps single-byte slices, empty slice

Comment: If I do `word='python' word[2:3] == word[2:-3]`, I get `true`. And if I compare `id(word[2:3])` and `id(word[2:-3])`, they are the same. Does it means when slicing, python does some interning work for the identical strings?

Comment: `memoryview` doesn't really help for strings, because it only works on objects which support the buffer protocol, like `bytes` and `bytearray`

Answer (score 0):

When you slice strings, they return a new instance of String. Strings are immutable objects.

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question: he's asking if the data gets copied or not.

Comment: This is a reason why you'd expect slice views to _not_ copy. One of the common uses for immutable data is it's easy to pass references instead. So I'm curious why in Python it does a copy.