# Why is regex search in substring "not completely equivalent to slicing the string" in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.regex.search) stated, using `regex.search(string, pos, endpos)` is not completely equivalent to slicing the string, i.e. `regex.search(string[pos:endpos])`. It won't do regex matching *as if* the string is starting from `pos`, so `^` does not match the beginning of the *substring*, but only matches the real beginning of the whole string. However, `$` matches either the end of the substring or the whole string.

```
    >>> re.compile('^am').findall('I am falling in code', 2, 12)
    []        # am is not at the beginning
    >>> re.compile('^am').findall('I am falling in code'[2:12])
    ['am']    # am is the beginning
    >>> re.compile('ing$').findall('I am falling in code', 2, 12)
    ['ing']   # ing is the ending
    >>> re.compile('ing$').findall('I am falling in code'[2:12])
    ['ing']   # ing is the ending

    >>> re.compile('(?<= )am').findall('I am falling in code', 2, 12)
    ['am']    # before am there is a space
    >>> re.compile('(?<= )am').findall('I am falling in code'[2:12])
    []        # before am there is no space
    >>> re.compile('ing(?= )').findall('I am falling in code', 2, 12)
    []        # after ing there is no space
    >>> re.compile('ing(?= )').findall('I am falling in code'[2:12])
    []        # after ing there is no space

    >>> re.compile(r'\bm.....').findall('I am falling in code', 3, 11)
    []
    >>> re.compile(r'\bm.....').findall('I am falling in code'[3:11])
    ['m fall']
    >>> re.compile(r'.....n\b').findall('I am falling in code', 3, 11)
    ['fallin']
    >>> re.compile(r'.....n\b').findall('I am falling in code'[3:11])
    ['fallin']
```

My questions are... Why is it not consistent between *beginning* and *ending* match? Why does using `pos` and `endpos` treat the *end* as the real end, but the *start/beginning* is not treated as the real start/beginning?

Is there any approach to make using `pos` and `endpos` imitate slicing? Because Python [copies string when slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722068/1197317) instead of just reference the old one, it would be more efficient to use `pos` and `endpos` instead of slicing when working with big string multiple times.

Comment: Very strange, it seems that the new regex module has the same behaviour.

Comment: It looks worth a bug report to python: http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: @ArminRigo But the documentation told it, so it might be a "feature" :)

Comment: This is consistent with what the documentation says (it says that using `endpos` is equivalent to slicing). It is however very weird behaviour but I suspect that a bug report would be rejected on the grounds that changing this would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: A different point of view is that the start "pos" argument is meant for doing multiple search() to locate several matches in a left-to-right manner.  The "endpos" on the other hand is meant to pretend the string is really sliced to this length.  I suppose it is consistent with the fact that there is no "search_rightmost()" function to do right-to-left multiple search.

Comment: I'm guessing you expect the second from bottom statement to return an empty list. Is that right? Can you clarify what you expect to happen in these examples?

Comment: @mehtunguh About `re.compile(r'.....n\b').findall('I am falling in code', 3, 11)`, I expect nothing because the documentation has stated that, I give up :D. I am just curious why they are inconsistent. Additionally, I would like to know is there any approach to make using `pos/endpos` imitate slicing.

Comment: If you specifically want to use `^` to match the beginning of the string, could you use `re.match()` instead? I know this is not a general case solution - but maybe it's good enough for what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The starting position argument `pos` is especially useful for doing lexical analysers for example. The performance difference between slicing a string with `[pos:]` and using the `pos` parameter might seem insignificant, but it certainly is not so; see for example this bug report in the [JsLex lexer](https://bitbucket.org/ned/jslex/issues/1/jslex-is-slooow-on-big-javascript-files).

Indeed, the `^` matches at the real beginning of the string; or, if `MULTILINE` is specified, also at the beginning of line; this is also by design so that a scanner based on regular expressions can easily distinguish between **real** beginning of line/beginning of input and just some other point on a line/within the input.

Do note that you can also use the [`regex.match(string[, pos[, endpos]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) function to anchor the match to the beginning string **or** at the position specified by `pos`; thus instead of doing

```
>>> re.compile('^am').findall('I am falling in code', 2, 12)
[]
```

you'd generally implement a scanner as

```
>>> match = re.compile('am').match('I am falling in code', 2, 12)
>>> match
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 4), match='am'>
```

and then set the `pos` to `match.end()` (which in this case returns 4) for the successive matching operations.

The match must be found starting exactly at the `pos`:

```
>>> re.compile('am').match('I am falling in code', 1, 12)
>>>
```

(Notice how the `.match` is anchored at the beginning of the input as if by implicit `^` but not to the end of the input; indeed this is often a source of errors as people believe the match has both implicit `^` and `$` - Python 3.4 added the [`regex.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.fullmatch) that does this)

---

As for why the `endpos` parameter is not consistent with the `pos` - that I do not know exactly, but it also makes some sense to me, as in Python 2 there is no `fullmatch` and there anchoring with `$` is the only way to ensure that the entire span must be matched.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in Python, but if you want to do slice by reference instead of copying the strings you can use the Python builtin `buffer`.

For example:

```
s = "long string" * 100
buf = buffer(s)
substr = buf([5:15])
```

This creates a substring without copying the data, so should allow for efficient splitting of large strings.

Comment: Nice info about `buffer`, unfortunately it is not available in Python 3.

Comment: @BornToCode: Unfortunately, I haven't managed to get the Python3 replacement `memoryview` to work properly with string slices. I thought I'd mention buffer anyway because there are still many Python2 users, and the question didn't specify a version.

Comment: I'd be careful about making assumptions about the relationship between strings and buffers.  The latter are both byte-oriented, while strings (and regexes) operate on full Unicode, especially in Python3.  So, the slice `s[2:4]` refers to two *characters*, however they may be represented as 3 to 6 *bytes*.  That means you need to be careful about assuming you can do raw memory operations on strings.  This suggests that the original poster should consider the big picture a bit more, and consider an algorithmic solution rather than delving too deep into micro-efficiencies of python code.