# What does str_var[:] mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing text for NLP. And I faced unfamiliar grammer below url.

`text[:]`
https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI/blob/master/parlai/core/dict.py#L39

I assume `text` is a natural sentence like `text = 'what does Duane Boutte appear in?'`. I know `:` with index number means array access like `text[:3] -> 'wha'`. But I do not know without index number. And I also know `:` is used for access to multi dimensional array like `data[:][:3]`.

Could you image above link's `text[:]`? This function split sentence to tokens.

### Update

I found it is a copy operation. See Martijn Pieters and Jean-François Fabre comments

Comment: It creates a copy from start to end; it is sometimes called the *identity slice*.

Comment: Thanks! Is it same as `copy.deepcopy(text)`?

Comment: rather like `copy.copy(text)`

Comment: Nice. I don't know that. If it's' possible, could you post your comment as an answer? I will mark it as an answer

Comment: errr, no since it's a duplicate. but thanks.

Comment: note that identity slice on a string does nothing useful since strings are immutable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722006/does-python-do-slice-by-reference-on-strings