What's the time complexity of this recursive function?
Was asked to tell the order of growth of following function:
def lenRecur(s):
   if s == '':
      return 0
   else:
      return 1 + lenRecur(s[1:])

Should be O(n²) where n = len(s). But was given O(n) as correct.
Each recursive call being made len(s) times multiplied by len(s) - 1 times for slicing? Is it wrong?

Why is "multipled by len(s)-1 times for slicing"?

Welcome to the site! Please see: How do I ask and answer homework questions?, Open letter to students with homework problems

@ScottHunter doesn't the slicing make the clone for the string?

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722068/

(Feel free to tell your professor/teacher this): I really don't like asking this type of question as a homework assignment, because you're right: this depends on the time complexity of the s[1:] operation. Your intuition that it scales with n, the size of the string, is right for the default CPython implementations of strings, but that's not guaranteed. E.g. I believe that the library numpy implements its slicing as a "shadowing" where the array is kept the same in memory, but you get an object that only sees part of it.

@AbdulMoiz without reading the full assignment, one explanation is they're asking not for the time complexity, but the order of the depth of the recursion. E.g. this will make O(n) calls to lenRecurs, That, or the writer of the question didn't realize list/array slicing had O(n) performance. Either way, it's vague. If there's a way to provide feedback, you definitely should.

Please add the missing details that tell us (and you, of course) what happens when this code runs (as per the comments: is this Python? Numpy? We don't know), because "Was asked to tell the order of growth of following function" means you were almost certainly given specifics about the rest of the program. If you weren't, then the only answer is "we don't know, because we don't know what underlying behaviour this code has".

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans since the course didn't introduce numpy we may assume its just about python. The question is from archived version of MITx 6.00.1 2018. I'm following OSSU curriculum. The next question was also marked seemingly incorrect. Recursive Binary search with recursive calls including slicing the list in either half depending on condition. Considering the time complexity of slicing too it would take n log n being n = len(list) but was marked simply long(n).

Don't tell me. Tell everyone by putting those details in your post.
