# Python: most effcient way to strip line from text file

Tags: python, string, list

How does one go about a for loop and changing the entries in the list?  Like, the equivalent of `[line.strip() for line in lines]`, except that `line.strip()` is saved back to the lines list.

This is needed because I am using a large dataset, stored in the list.  This dataset will be used to for machine training to train a classifier.  Specifically, natural language processing using the NLTK lib.  Hence, duplication of the array is not feasible.

Comment: Do you mean actually editing the file?

Comment: I think he means he wants all non-empty lines - empty lines should just disappear from his list.

Comment: Most efficient in what terms? Speed? Memory consumption? ... ?

Comment: Number of lines written and intepreted.

Comment: What do you mean by "saved back to the lines list"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator expression, then all lines won't be held at the same time.

```
glines = (line.strip() for line in lines)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

which creates another list (though it's all stored in memory which may be a problem with a lot of lines).

*Alternatively*, you could use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead to avoid the potential memory problem and just create the lines on demand:

```
lines = (line.strip() for line in lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to store the result into the same instance `lines` (not replace with a new list instance)?

```
lines[:] = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't the right hand side of this assignment create a whole new list anyway?

Comment: @srgerg, yes, it creates new list first then replaces the whole content of `lines` with contents of this new list. But it is the fastest way to store the result into the same list instance (if talking about arbitrary length lists).

Comment: ok, but then why not use a generator expression on the right-hand-side to reduce the memory requirements of constructing the whole list?

Comment: @srgerg: The statement with a generator expression might create a copy anyway in CPython (see how `list_ass_*` functions are implemented in listobject.c)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to strip the lines from a file *in place* rather than creating an entirely new list. The problem is that in Python [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538685/631586), so you can't modify a string in place, you must create a new one.

As others have suggested, a generator expression will produce the stripped strings on demand, rather than storing them all in a new list, reducing memory demands. If you *really* want to strip the strings in place, then something like this will do the job:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines): lines[i] = line.strip()
```

but it may be that creating a new list would be faster anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  Answered the question.  Wanted to avoid creating another duplicate list, because it will contain test datasets used for machine training and the list might be quite large.  Thanks!