# Why can't I modify (change the value/contents of) a tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

Suppose I create a tuple like so:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3,)
```

I want to modify it:

```
>>> a[0] = 10
```

But this causes an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Why is it not possible to modify the tuple?

Comment: Because tuples are immutable. If you want mutable sequences, use lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: changing value in a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458239/python-changing-value-in-a-tuple)

Comment: Tuples can't be changed because they were designed that way. If your question is why they were designed that way (or why Python has both immutable and mutable sequence types), that comes down to efficiency. When you know a sequence can't change, you can allocate exactly the right amount of memory for it (lists use padding, to allow items to be added with constant overhead) and you can store only one copy of a given sequence no matter how many times it is used in the program  (called "interning").

Answer (score 1):

`tuples`, like `strings`, are immutable objects in that their values cannot be changed once they have been created. You usually use `tuples` when you want to store a list of values that you wont be editing, maybe they are constants. If you will be editing, resizing or appending elements to the `tuple`, use `lists` instead.

You can do it either as follows:

```
a = (10, a[1], a[2])
```

Or using lists. Lists are much more dynamic and allow item assignment and editing.

For example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a[0] = 10
>>> a
[10,2,3]
```

Comment: I know that. i just want to know about tuple a[0].

Comment: @Danielsss, As I explained in my answer, tuples are immutable type objects in python. You cannot edit them once you create them.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple), tuples are immutable sequence types. This means you cannot change them.