# generate a modified copy of a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

I know I can't modify a tuple and I've seen ways to create a tuple from another one concatenating parts of the original manually like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458239/python-changing-value-in-a-tuple).

But wonder whether there has emerged some pythonic way to 'modify' a tuple by implicitly creating a new one like

```
>>> source_tuple = ('this', 'is', 'the', 'old', 'tuple')
>>> new_tuple = source_tuple.replace(3, 'new')
>>> new_tuple
('this', 'is', 'the', 'new', 'tuple')
```

A possible implementation could look like this but I'm looking for a *built in* solution:

```
def replace_at(source, index, value):
    if isinstance(source, tuple):
        return source[:index] + (value,) + source[index + 1:]
    elif isinstance(source, list):
        return source[:index] + [value,] + source[index + 1:]
    else:
        explode()
```

it's not much work to implement such a functionality but like the `Enum` has demonstrated it's sometimes better to have an implementation everyone uses..

**Edit**: my goal is *not* to replace the source tuple. I know I could use lists but even in this case I would make a copy first. So I'm really just looking for a way to create a modified copy.

Comment: That's what lists are for...

Comment: `tuple(u' '.join(source_tuple).replace('old', 'new').split(u' '))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

You can use a slice on the tuple (which yields a new tuple) and concatenate:

```
>>> x=3
>>> new_tuple=source_tuple[0:x]+('new',)+source_tuple[x+1:]
>>> new_tuple
('this', 'is', 'the', 'new', 'tuple')
```

Which you can then support either a list or tuple like so:

```
>>> def replace_at(source, index, value):
...     return source[0:index]+type(source)((value,))+source[index+1:]
...
>>> replace_at([1,2,3],1,'new')
[1, 'new', 3]
>>> replace_at((1,2,3),1,'new')
(1, 'new', 3)
```

Or, just do it directly on a list:

```
>>> source_tuple = ('this', 'is', 'the', 'old', 'tuple')
>>> li=list(source_tuple)
>>> li[3]='new'
>>> new_tuple=tuple(li)
>>> new_tuple
('this', 'is', 'the', 'new', 'tuple')
```

As stated in the comments -- that is what lists are for...

Comment: You can do it like this of course but you have to admit that this code is neither short nor intuitive since it's three lines of code with two type casts just saying "replace element 3 with 'new'"

Comment: Try a slice then: `new_tuple=source_tuple[0:3]+('new',)+source_tuple[4:]`

Comment: This is what I wrote :)

Comment: Rather than the `if/then` you can do: `source[0:index]+type(source)((value,))+source[index+1:]`

Comment: This is not exactly what I was hoping to find but you can't change Python for me :). Your answer demonstrates nice approaches so I'll choose it!

Answer (score 3):

If you're thinking of swapping values on the fly, then a `list` is the more appropriate data structure; as we already know tuples are *immutable*.

On another note, if you're looking for a *swap-value* logic in a `tuple`, you can have a look at [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) which has a `_replace` method.

> They can be used wherever regular tuples are used

```
>>> source_tuple = ('this', 'is', 'the', 'old', 'tuple')

>>> Factory = namedtuple('Factory', range(5), rename=True)

>>> source_tuple = Factory(*source_tuple)

>>> source_tuple
Factory(_0='this', _1='is', _2='the', _3='old', _4='tuple')

>>> new_tuple = source_tuple._replace(_3='new')

>>> new_tuple
Factory(_0='this', _1='is', _2='the', _3='new', _4='tuple')
```

Well that doesn't look too elegant. I still suggest you use a `list` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of comprehension:

```
source_tuple = ('this', 'is', 'the', 'old', 'tuple')
new_tuple = tuple((value if x != 3 else 'new'
                   for x, value in enumerate(source_tuple)))
# ('this', 'is', 'the', 'new', 'tuple')
```

This is rather idotic in this case but gives you an idea of the general concept. Better use a **list**, though, after all, you can change the values index-based here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create new tuple with replaced element, you may use something like this:

```
def replace_value_in_tuple(t, ind, value):
    return tuple(
        map(lambda i: value if i == ind else t[i], range(len(t)))
    )
```