# Finding if letter = another letter in python

Tags: python

This is in python and I'm having a little trouble finding this out, I put.

```
s = 'goodbye'
```

and I want to know if the first letter is a g. 
so i put

```
s[0] = 'g'
```

but i get an error, what is the right way to finding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `=` means 'assignment', and doing two `==` means 'compare and see if they're equal'. The difference between the two can be subtle (just a single character difference!), so make sure you don't get confused between the two

You want `s[0] == 'g'`:

```
if s[0] == 'g':
    print "word starts with 'g'"
```

Doing `s[0] = 'g'` is telling Python "change the first letter of the string to 'g'". However, that fails because in Python, strings are [*immutable*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538663/646543) -- they can never be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `startswith(prefix)` method (returns True if string starts with the prefix, otherwise returns False):

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> a = s.startswith('h')
>>> a
True
```