# Python changing file name

Tags: python-3.x

My application offers the ability to the user to export its results. My application exports text files with name `Exp_Text_1`, `Exp_Text_2` etc. I want it so that if a file with the same file name pre-exists in Desktop then to start counting from this number upwards. For example if a file with name `Exp_Text_3` is already in Desktop, then I want the file to be created to have the name `Exp_Text_4`.

This is my code:

```
if len(str(self.Output_Box.get("1.0", "end"))) == 1:
            self.User_Line_Text.set("Nothing to export!")
        else:
            import os.path

            self.txt_file_num = self.txt_file_num + 1
            file_name = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "Exp_Txt" + "_" + str(self.txt_file_num) + ".txt")

            file = open(file_name, "a")
            file.write(self.Output_Box.get("1.0", "end"))
            file.close()

            self.User_Line_Text.set("A text file has been exported to Desktop!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you likely want `os.path.exists`:

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os.path.exists)
Help on function exists in module genericpath:

exists(path)
    Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links
```

a very basic example would be create a file name with a formatting mark to insert the number for multiple checks:

```
import os

name_to_format = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "Exp_Txt_{}.txt")
#the "{}" is a formatting mark so we can do file_name.format(num)

num = 1
while os.path.exists(name_to_format.format(num)):
    num+=1

new_file_name = name_to_format.format(num)
```

this would check each filename starting with `Exp_Txt_1.txt` then `Exp_Txt_2.txt` etc. until it finds one that does not exist.

However the format mark may cause a problem if curly brackets `{}` are part of the rest of the path, so it may be preferable to do something like this:

```
import os

def get_file_name(num):
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "Exp_Txt_" + str(num) + ".txt")

num = 1
while os.path.exists(get_file_name(num)):
    num+=1

new_file_name = get_file_name(num)
```

---

EDIT: answer to **why don't we need `get_file_name` function in first example?**

First off if you are unfamiliar with `str.format` you may want to look at [Python doc - common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and/or this simple example:

```
text = "Hello {}, my name is {}."
x = text.format("Kotropoulos","Tadhg")
print(x)
print(text)
```

The path string is figured out with this line:

```
 name_to_format = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "Exp_Txt_{}.txt")
```

But it has `{}` in the place of the desired number. (since we don't know what the number should be at this point) so if the path was for example:

```
 name_to_format = "/Users/Tadhg/Desktop/Exp_Txt_{}.txt"
```

then we can insert a number with:

```
print(name_to_format.format(1))
print(name_to_format.format(2))
```

and this does not change `name_to_format` since `str` objects are [Immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538663/why-are-python-strings-and-tuples-are-made-immutable) so the `.format` returns a new string without modifying `name_to_format`.  However we would run into a problem if out path was something like these:

```
 name_to_format = "/Users/Bob{Cat}/Desktop/Exp_Txt_{}.txt"
 #or
 name_to_format = "/Users/Bobcat{}/Desktop/Exp_Txt_{}.txt"
 #or
 name_to_format = "/Users/Smiley{:/Desktop/Exp_Txt_{}.txt"
```

Since the formatting mark we want to use is no longer the only curly brackets and we can get a variety of errors:

```
 KeyError: 'Cat'
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
 ValueError: unmatched '{' in format spec
```

So you only want to rely on `str.format` when you know it is safe to use.  Hope this helps, have fun coding!

Comment: Because I am a new Python user, why in this example we don't need to call the function get_file_name?

Comment: I added an explanation but I may have misinterpreted `why in this example we don't need to call the function get_file_name?`

Comment: I mean that in order to execute a Python function we need to call it. In this example there isn't a call for get_file_name function.

Comment: ... the first example doesn't need the function because it works differently, and in the second example I call it in two places, one after the while loop and once in the conditional of the while loop